# jodit react , icons are very big in size, the editor is not appearing in its proper form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, wysiwyg, jodit

Basically, the editor has oversized icons and are so big, and it looks so ugly, so i am not sure what is causing this, but i have not added any css to it, so it is not modified by design

code:

```
import JoditEditor from "jodit-react";

function Comp(){
return(

<div> <JoditEditor></JoditEditor> </div>     ) }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Fpu2.jpg

icons are big

and then when i scroll down:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9cqn.jpg

as you see

the editor is supposed to look like this:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Can you check the below sandbox example.

https://codesandbox.io/s/jodit-react-editor-demo-forked-kpu137?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: posting the very official example as a solution is not a solution.